# 2nd phase compilation in templates

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to understand the compilation process and the code generation process in c++ template universe.

I have read that during the first phase of compilation only the basic syntax is checked(in templated code). 
And that the actual code is generated only for those data types which are used for which the compilation is done completely- this is termed as second phase compilation.

1. I am not able to understand that how can a compiler know for which data type can the templated code be called and for which to generate the code(and hence do 2nd phase compilation). There might be cases when the function calls(in case off function templates) might not be so strightforward to derive the datatype during compile time, these can be derived only during runtime basedon input from user.
2. Assuming i have a written a huge code using templates with a lot of conditions based on which it generates new instance of templated code(lets say new instance of datatype for a class). I cant test the code for all the data types. So does it mean that if i test it for a couple of data types, there are still chances of my code failing unexpectedly for some other data types? If so, how can i ensure to force 2nd compilation for all the data types(irrespective of that data type based on my input is instantiated or not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The types determined during compilation time only rely on the static information. A function template that is used with a particular type will generate code for that type, since the option needs to be available in the runtime. If it can be statically determined that a function call will *never* happen, though, I think that the compiler might omit that implementation, but there are certain cases that'd still force that.
2. You can't test for *all* datatypes, since that's an infinite set. You can create a set of all standard types, but you obviously can't check every user-defined type ever. The idea in generic code is to not depend on the particulars of the type you're allowing to pass it. Alternatively, you might close the set of possible instances to *only* include the types you sanction.

Comment: For 1. question still remains. What happens during runtime when the compiler doesnt generate the code because it thinks that the datatype will not be used. For 2. Is there no forceful check to atleast fully compile for all datatypes? any code may be? Or a tool? any hack or any such thing?

Comment: @anurag86 If it can't be used, then it won't ever go into that code? If you hack around it, then the most interesting that can happen is just a crash. And not really. Unless you're creating a very primitive template type, you can't really be sure that it'll work for every case. But then again, it's typically enough to check edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

> I am not able to understand that how can a compiler know for which data type can the templated code be called

The compiler knows for which data types the templated code **is** actually called because it sees every place in the program where the templated code is actually called. No magic here. Instantiation happens at call sites. No instantiation is done for types that are not used in actual existing calls.

> there are still chances of my code failing

This is true for all test-based validation, templates or no templates, and even for things other than software. You cannot cover all possible use cases by tests. It's a fundamental fact of life. Deal with it... somehow.